# Nested Array not updating value when passed new value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a function that when passed the parameters id (location of element), marker (updated value requested), array (nested array) it should run through a loop to match the id with the correct nested location.

It should then take the nested location and find those elements on the nested array to update it with the requested value. Though when I attempt to get it to update the value and test its working, all I am receiving in the terminal is the location of the element and not an updated array.

Am I doing something wrong with updating the nested array? This is the code

```
function BoardManipulation(id, marker, array) { 
  let match;

  for (let i = 0; i < translation.length; i++) {
    if(JSON.stringify(translation[i].id) === JSON.stringify(id)) {
      match = translation[i].value;
      return match
    } 
  } 
  let newArr = array[match[0]][match[1]] = marker;
  console.log(newArr)
}

let board = [["X", "O", "X"], ["X", "O", "_"], ["_", "X", "_"]];
const game = BoardManipulation(7, 'O', board);
console.log(game)
```

This is the translation piece that the id is checked against.

```
let translation = [
  { id: 0, value: [0, 0] },
  { id: 1, value: [0, 1] },
  { id: 2, value: [0, 2] },
  { id: 3, value: [1, 0] },
  { id: 4, value: [1, 1] },
  { id: 5, value: [1, 2] },
  { id: 6, value: [2, 0] },
  { id: 7, value: [2, 1] },
  { id: 8, value: [2, 2] },
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; there's a `return` in the middle of `BoardManipulation` so the code _after_ that will never execute. Unrelated, but functions are typically named with a leading lower-case unless they're a constructor.

Comment: Yeah was working with constructors before this so just accidentally carried it across. The return is for the if statement which returns match with the nested array location.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what the `return` statement does. A `return` is used to return from functions (not loops). Functions exit when they hit a `return`.

Comment: You was right, I had the return in the wrong place and was not returning the new array. Thanks!

Comment: Great; glad you worked it out!